# How can I use a th:object in a form but skip a field inside the form in thymeleaf spring boot

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Im sending an object to this form from a controller, everything works fine in my html:

```
<form th:action="@{/sgc/modificarObraPost}" th:object="${obra}"method="POST"
                                enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nombre"><b>Nombre nuevo de la Obra</b></label>
                            <input class="form-control " type="text" th:field="*{nombre}" th:value="${nombre}" th:name="nombreobra" id="nombreobra">  
                        </div> 

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="descripcion"><b>Genero</b></label>
                            <select th:name="genero" class="form-control ">
                            <option th:each="gene : ${genero}" th:field="*{genero}" th:value="${gene.getNombre()}" th:text="${gene.getNombre()}">genero</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>   

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nombre"><b>Cantidad Vendida</b></label>
                            <input class="form-control " type="text" th:field="*{cantidadVendidas}" th:value="${vendido}" th:name="vendido" id="vendido">  
                        </div>                                       

                        <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="imagen"><b> Sube tu Imagen</b></label> <input
                                        class="form-control-file" type="file" size="50"
                                        placeholder="sube la imagen" th:name="imagen" id="imagen"
                                        accept="image/png,image/jpeg" onChange="verNombre()"/>
                                </div>
                        <div class="pull-right row-mt-6em">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md pull-right">Modificar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

The problem is that I don't want to have the last input (the image input) added as a field to my object in the form since there is a type miss match and i want to get this image with @RequestParam and set it in my other controller.
Is there something like th:notfield or something so my form doesnt think I want to modify that field in my object?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you want to make an update in an already existing object
You can delete the following div from the html page

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="imagen"><b> Sube tu Imagen</b></label> 
     <input
           class="form-control-file" type="file" size="50"
           placeholder="sube la imagen" th:name="imagen" id="imagen"
           accept="image/png,image/jpeg" onChange="verNombre()"/>
 </div>
```

Then, in your controller and more specifically in the request mapping that you handle the update (/sgc/modificarObraPost) you could write the following lines of code

```
Obra obraOriginal = getById(obra.getId()); //get the object that is in the database that you want to modify
String[] ignoreProperties = { "nombre", "genero", "cantidadVendidas"}; //you want to ignore properties that you pass from the front page
BeanUtils.copyProperties(obra, obraOriginal, ignoreProperties); //the obra object is the object that you pass in the controller
```

This way you create an object obra that has all the original properties plus the ones that you have from the form.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear,I do want to update an existing object with new data but I also want to update the image in the object only if its a new image, to do that I use a function in a controller so is there a way to update all the data in my object from the html except the image so i can send it as a param and do it from my controller?